# SQL table comparison, build query and print filtered data into dropdown list

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a stored value from one table called user_id.  I have another table as such:

client_projects:

```
+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| project_codename | client_id_1 | client_id_2 | client_id_3 |
+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|       Alpha      |      1      |      2      |      3      |
+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|       Beta       |      2      |      1      |      0      |
+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|       Gamma      |      3      |      1      |      0      |
+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

If the user_id = (client_id_1 or client_id_2 or client_id_3) then I want to print the corresponding project_codenames in a dropdown list. This is the php I have but is not returning the right results. I have marketed the areas I am unsure of.

PHP(updated and solved):

```
<?php

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","****","****","db") or die("Connection error: " . mysqli_error($con));

  //stored sample value from another table 
  $user_id = "1";

  //Build query: Not sure if this is correct format
  $query = "SELECT * FROM client_projects WHERE client_id_1 = $user_id OR client_id_2 = $user_id OR client_id_3 = $user_id";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query error: " . mysqli_error($con));

  //Drop down list
  echo '<select id="Projects" class="input">';
  echo '<option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose a Project...</option>';

  // Loop through the query results, outputing specific options one by one
  // Not sure of the loop for the options
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['project_codename'].'">'.$row['project_codename'].'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: In addition to the missing mysqli steps per Roman's answer, your query is using IN incorrectly. You should instead write it as client_id_1 = ? OR client_id_2 = ? OR client_id_3 = ?

Comment: Michael is right. If You're not sure if Your query is correct, check mysqli_query()'s return value and optionally use [mysqli_error()](http://us3.php.net/mysqli_error) function to display complete error message the server sent You.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Anderson I've updated the code above and tested but still getting a syntax error in the $query.  Am I not coding it right?

Comment: I've update the code once again to what worked for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're feeding the $query directly into mysqli_fetch_array(), but this function expects a result resource as an input. You're missing the mysqli_query() call. See Example #2 at [manual page](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array)